# do temple deities acquire power from devotees?

Tags: gods, temple

i understand the idols are empowered by vedic chanting that is drawn into water and the idol bathed in the potent water.

is there also a hindu tradition that the deity is empowered by the devotees who visit the temple?

Comment: Don't know about temple but all devas got power from yagya performed by us. Only Trideva don't need any power because he himself source of power. The power that devas got from us is also power of trideva. We are just medium to give Trideva's power to all devas.